# typedef templates in global scope

Tags: c++, templates, scope, typedef

using template classes I usually make some typedefs
like:

```
typedef super<puper<complex<template<type> > > > simple_name
```

I usually do it in 2 ways:

```
template <class A, ...>
struct Types {
    typedef ...
}

template <class A, ...>
class Part_Of_Logick {
    public:
        typedef ...
}
```

Is it possible to set typedefs at the global scope?
like this:

```
template <class A, ...>
typedef ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand that you mean writing a templated `typedef` that will create a second template with some of the arguments of the first template fixed. If that is the question, no, not in the current standard. In the upcoming c++0x standard you will be able to do:

```
template <typename A, typename B> a_template;
template <typename T>
using other_template = a_template<T, int>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not in C++98. C++0x will support this. I can't exactly recall the C++0x syntax, though.

Cheers & hth.,

– Alf